# how to send hidden SMS

Tags: sms, smpp

I am using SMPP (v3.4) to sending hidden SMS which it is not show to the user on handset.

My application is java base and use JSMPP.  It works fine with normal text SMS. but i don't know how to implement for hidden SMS.  Can anyone advise on it? Thanks

Comment: this seems suspiciously malicious

Comment: I found can use binary SMS via SMPP

Answer (score 1):

Set DATA_CODING to hexadecimal c0